# Need custom error page for HTTP response codes in Jenkins

Tags: security, jenkins, redirect, http-status-codes

Our security team wants custom pages for https response code 403 and 404.

Also, is it possible to redirect Http response 403 to Http response 404 back to the user so that sensitive data is not revealed to the end user?

So, basically we wish to hide the below response from Jenkins to the end user.

```
403 No valid crumb was included in the request
```

A custom error page for jenkins still has no solution [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-62890)

Thus, redirecting 403 to 404 response will help temporarily.

Can this be achieved? Kindly help guide.